# Excel to ElasticSearch API Requests

Tags: excel, rest, api, elasticsearch, vba

I searched the internet and could not find good examples. I am new to ES and programming as well.

I am trying to connect directly from Excel to ElasticSearch cluster.. I am trying to write the API request in its entirety. I have tried a few things.. need some more help here. Here is what, I was able to do.

```
Sub MyFirstRESTAPICALL()
    Dim oRequest As Object
    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oRequest.Open "GET", "http://my-es-node1:9200"
    MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
End Sub
```

I get a simple response in my excel, but I need to do more.

How do I construct GET request that can be used from Excel to ElasticSearch? The query I am using in kibana is below. I need to translate it and update the GET request above.

```
GET DJ_cust_latest/cust/_search?size=100 {
    "_source":["cust-_info-_version", "cust-config-num", "num_tables"], 
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {"terms":
                    {"cust_uuid":[
                        "00845916-3245-dcbf-0000-87650000d98c",
                        "00634297-1718-f280-0000-00000897e522"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs and understanding the query string syntax a little more better, I reached the conclusion that querying ElasticSearch (ES) from Excel is not only a nightmare (writing the query string syntax etc..) but also very inefficient as parsing the Json output will also be painful. So, I am planning to do the ES in Shell scripts, getting raw Json data, create CSV's and then process it in Excel.